# ¿Como prevenir accidentes de sentencias con la base de datos de producción MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hace poco trabajaba con mi base de datos local y accidentalmente trunqué la base de datos que estaba en producción :(, afortunadamente tenia un backup reciente, actualmente uso workbench para trabajar las bases de datos, la pregunta es. ¿existe una manera de evitar este tipo de sentencias si se está en producción (*truncate o update/delete sin where*)?, tal vez que solicite una clave antes de hacer una de estas sentencias, o un mensaje de alerta o cualquier cosa que pueda ayudar a evitarlo

Comment: Permisos a los usuarios, busca sobre grant para que indiques según el usuario qué tipo de acciones puede llevar a cabo sobre la base de datos

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Como comenta @element, la mejor forma de prevenir esto es administrando bien los permisos. Ahora, si eres el administrador de la BD y eres el que ha truncado la tabla significa que debes tener cuidado con lo que haces. No hay peor virus que el usuario. Es él el que le da al botón, el que abre un link prometedor que enlaza a un sitio que llena el dispositivo de virus. Por tanto: precaución máxima si eres administrador y a nivel de código controlar el uso que hace cada uno de los recursos/privilegios de la base de datos mediante niveles de permiso y demás.